# Buscar informações no banco de dados em uma linha de código SQL por usuário logado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Já consegui buscar todas as datas do banco de dados. Porém, eu gostaria de buscar através de um ID específico que está logado no sistema. Por sessão, no caso.
Porém esse código está dando erro na parte em que eu coloco o HttpContext.
Alguma sugestão sobre o que mudar?

```
public static Dictionary<object, object> SelecionaLinhasBancoLista()
    {

        Dictionary<object, object> dic = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        string sql = "";
        sql = "SELECT dayname(carrinho.Data), count(day(carrinho.Data)) as quantidade FROM foodintime.carrinho where carrinho.restauranteid = "+ HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"] +"group by day(carrinho.Data)";

        using (var ctx = new Context())
        using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var model = Read(reader).ToList();

                string[] dias = new string[] { "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo" };

                foreach (var item in model)
                {


                    dic.Add(item.GetValue(0), item.GetValue(1));

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allan

está faltando um espaço dentre a aspas e o group by no seu select.

```
"+ HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"] +" group by
```

Comment: Não acredito que era só isso! KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK muito obrigado, Alexandre.

Comment: kkkk, isso acontece acho que mais vezes do que eu gostaria. Se precisar estamos as ordens.